# Prove that the following logical implication is true

Tags: logic, model-theory

Taking advantage of the model theory, prove that
$M \cong N  \implies M \equiv N$

Comment: What is the context? Model theory, with $\cong$ as isomorphism and $\equiv$ as elementary equivalence?

Comment: Yes, that is the context. Forgive me for not mentioning that.

Comment: Please write a full question. Not just a title and some formula. Try to include some context, too. No one here can read minds (I hope).

Comment: With all due respect, that is the full question. For other notes, please refer to the post just above:

"The context is the model theory, with ≅ as isomorphism and ≡ as elementary equivalence."

Comment: This follows almost immediately by the definition of isomorphism and elementary equivalence. What did you try to do so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It's not proper etiquette to post a question without showing what you've already done to attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I admit this is the first time I'm using this site. I wasn't completely aware of how it works here. Shame on me then, next time I'll post only attempted problems.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $h:M\to N$ be an isomorphism. Show by induction on the complexity of $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ that $M\vDash\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ iff $N\vDash\varphi\big(h(a_1),\dots,h(a_n)\big)$. (By now you should have seen several such proofs.) From this it follows immediately that $M\equiv N$.